# Having trouble with all my events being allDay events

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm having trouble with getting my events to NOT be allDay events.  I have allDay set to false in my JSON feed.  Here is what my JSON feed looks like:

```
{"title":"Welcome and Introduction  ","start":"8/15/2011 8:00:00 AM","end":"8/15/2011 8:15:00 AM","allDay":"False"}
```

As you can see, allDay is false, but all of my events are displaying as All Day events.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the quotes around `False` and lowercase it.

It should be `"allDay": false`

From the [Event Object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) documentation

> Don't include quotes around your true/false. This value is not a string!